# How to assign number to every unique element in order as it appears in the list of elements in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a list of elements ordered by time.

| ID | TIME |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2020-03-01 |
| A | 2020-03-02 |
| B | 2020-03-05 |
| B | 2020-03-06 |
| B | 2020-03-07 |
| B | 2020-03-08 |
| C | 2020-03-10 |
| C | 2020-03-15 |

Now, I would like to assign an unique number to every alphabetized ID incrementally (unique element from the list) something like A=1, B=2, C=3, etc.

Therefore, the final table should be looked like:

| ID | TIME | Uniq_val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020-03-01 | 1 |
| A | 2020-03-02 | 1 |
| B | 2020-03-05 | 2 |
| B | 2020-03-06 | 2 |
| B | 2020-03-07 | 2 |
| B | 2020-03-08 | 2 |
| C | 2020-03-10 | 3 |
| C | 2020-03-15 | 3 |

Due to the uncountable number of unique ID, it seems almost impossible to assign by mapping from ID to uniq_val.

Which functions would be the most useful in this case?

Comment: Could you also provide a sample code of your list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `pd.factorize`

```
codes, uniques = pd.factorize(df['id'])
df['uniq_val'] = codes
```

Or you can use `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
enc = LabelEncoder()
df['uniq_val'] = enc.fit_transform(df['id'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `ord` function which converts a character to ASCII code. ASCII code for `A` is 65, so by subtracting the value by 65 you can convert them to numbers:

```py
df['Uniq_val'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda id: ord(id)-65)
```

Full code, assuming you are using `pandas` DataFrame as below:

```py
import pandas as pd

columns = ['ID', 'TIME']
inp = [
    ('A', '2020-03-01'),
    ('A', '2020-03-02'),
    ('B', '2020-03-05'),
    ('B', '2020-03-06'),
]

df = pd.DataFrame(inp, columns=columns)
df['Uniq_val'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda id: ord(id)-65)
```

Which gives

```py
  ID        TIME  Uniq_val
0  A  2020-03-01         0
1  A  2020-03-02         0
2  B  2020-03-05         1
3  B  2020-03-06         1
```